# How to change symbols to words with macros in C?

Tags: c, macros

How can i change symbol to word in c?
(For example change % to word mod)

Example code:

```
Before:    a = a%2;

After:     a = a mod 2;
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, show us what you have tried till now based on that we can help.

Comment: As a starter try to write `#define mod %` at the top of your sourcefile.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your question. So to define a macro use this:

```
#define macro do_this
```

So in your example:

```
#define mod %
```

#define actually creates a constant, and during compiling every time you use the macro (in this case *mod*) it changes your macro to the actual "real" code.

Here is a little example I created:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define main            int main(void) {
#define func_end        }
#define number          int
#define equals          =
#define mod             %
#define say_number(x)   printf("%d\n", (x));

main
        number a;

        a equals 5;
        a equals a  mod 2;

        say_number(a);
func_end
```

The macro *say_number* requires the parameter x, which is then used in the *printf* function as a parameter.

With this you can change symbols to words, but before using these macros read this article: https://pmihaylov.com/macros-in-c/, its about how to use macros and the difference between macros and functions.

I hope this answered your question.